# How to estimate the physical parameters of 40% Cu + 60% Mo alloy?

Tags: building-physics, alloys

I need to know, or estimate the physical characteristics of the alloy which consists 40% copper and 60% molybdenum. I know only:

- Density: $9.62 \frac{g}{cm^3}$
- Thermal conductivity: $223 \frac{W}{m·K}$
- Coefficient of thermal expansion $9.3 \cdot 10^{-6} \frac{1}{°C}$

How to calculate, or at least, estimate its boiling point, clectrical resistivity, Young's modulus, and Vickers hardness? Also partial answers are okay.

Comment: This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (notice the quotation marks). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information. And please include precisely which properties you want and why you haven't found them yourself yet.

Comment: try to found it with google, guy. I'm fail.

Comment: Hm, it wasn't easy to properly reformat your post, and next time I won't be with you. I hope I didn't change your intent, it was needed for this question to remain open.

Comment: Well, you are asking something from people, you are asking things which require professional metallurgy knowledge. This communication style is not okay. Note, a *"please google this for me"* sounds much worser as *"please solve my homework instead me"*.